# best practise for mtry and ntree random forest tuning using the ranger and caret packages

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, caret

I am implementing a random forest model using the ranger package.

I know you cannot specify ntree's in the tune grid for caret. I have seen some suggestions to determine the best mtry values and then run another model using the best value to determine the optimal ntrees (e.g. I have also seen some suggestions to run the ntree and mtry tuning together (not using the ranger package, e.g.)

I would like to know if one way is better than the other (when using grid searching), or are both methods are equally fine? I haven't been able to find a definitive answer on the best practice for this.

Note- I haven't provided a code as this is to do with the theory and not the coding itself :)